# Pandas. Apply function to create multiple columns based on mask

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I'm trying to apply a custom function to a column which will return 3 values for 3 existing columns. But I need to do this only for filtered rows by mask.
So, for example I have a function

```
def f(x):
  return pd.Series(["1", "2", "3"])
```

And I have a dataframe

```
pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[1,2,3],'C':[1,2,3],'X':[1,10,100]})
```

So, the task is to apply function `f()` to dataframe only when df['X']==10 and update values in df[['A','B','C']] accordingly with function return.

What I expect to see:

```
    A   B   C   X
0   1   1   1   1
1  "1" "2" "3"  10
2   3   3   3  100
```

What I did so far:

```
mask = df['X']==10
df[['A','B','C']] = np.where(mask, df['X'].apply(f), df[['A','B','C']] ))
```

But I'm receiving an error regarding `operands could not be broadcast together with shapes`..

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Could you perhaps post the desired solution with your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `mask` to update values:

```
df.loc[mask, ['A', 'B', 'C']] = df.loc[mask] \
                                  .apply(f, axis='columns') \
                                  .values
```

```
>>> df
   A  B  C    X
0  1  1  1    1
1  1  2  3   10
2  3  3  3  100
```

Comment: is it possible to make it with np.where? dataset is huge and .loc is very slow..

Comment: Also, you are applying function to [['A', 'B', 'C']], but should be to series df['X']

Comment: I'm receiving mistakes. But following worked: 
`df.loc[mask, ['A', 'B', 'C']] = df.loc[mask, ['X']].apply(f).T.values`